# When push the UIButton, change image in the image view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm new to Swift and I am trying the make a button. I want to when i push the button start the timer and change image in the image view.

My code;

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

func start()
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController2.updateTime as (ViewController2) -> () -> ())), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func updateTimer () {
    count += 1
    let hours = Int(count) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(count) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(count) % 60
    label.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds)
}

func reset()
{
    timer.invalidate()
    count = 0
    label.text = "00:00:00"

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : UIButton)
{
    if sender.currentTitle == " "
    {
        sender.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
        reset()
    }

    else

    {
        sender.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
        start()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBAction func tick(sender: UIButton)
{

    if checked
    {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"Rectangle1.png"), for: [])

        checked = false
    }
    else
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Rectangle2.png"), for: [])

        checked = true
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when i push the button, changes the picture of the button. How can i change the image in the image view?

Comment: then you should use image instead of sender , simply image.image = (typeimagename - it will automatically puts image )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the senders image.. which is your UIButton.. change this part of your code

wrong:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Rectangle1.png"), for: [])
...
sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Rectangle2.png"), for: [])
```

right:

```
image.image = UIImage(named:"Rectangle1.png")   
...
image.image = UIImage(named:"Rectangle2.png")
```

Comment: Hi @Marcio! For clarity I suggest to rename the variables as `imageView.image` instead of `image.image`

Comment: totally agree.. the code provided in the question does uses this name for his UIImageView :( im sorry, I know it might confuse other people

Answer (score 0):

Define the button as a IBOutlet and set a new image:

```
 button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle1.png"), for: .normal)
```